# how I can give my credentials with get_contents? php

Tags: php, credentials

I have looked at some examples and they use Curl in php etc but I just want a simple command that passes my credentials to a site so it can login and give me access to download a file. Current problem is when I try to use get_contents I get stuck at login page because it needs a login before it can allow a download so isnt there a way to send my login info before get_contents in php? Thanks

for example we can assume the website is located at www.confluence.com

Answer (score 1):

You're out of luck. `file_get_contents()` can only get content, hence the name. You can try to authenticate via the get syntax for standard authentication, like `http://username:password@example.com`.

If you have to post your credentials via HTTP POST, you'll have to use curl.

Comment: i tried http://username:password@confluence.rogersdigitalmedia.com but it didnt work, I was located at the login page, any ideas?

Comment: Is there some different restriction in place? I'm getting a 403 Error, just trying to access the login page..

Comment: u need to be on apache server to access it, only I can and people nearby that are in the team....This is so painful is there no way to pass the credentials?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you log in the server send to your browser a cookies that your browser automatically stores. 
With `file_get_content()` you can actually pass cookies ( the third `context` parameter of file_get_content() can handle this).

Have a look at [stream context create](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).
By the way, you need to first  send your  login info to the login page (with `curl`), when you recive cookies back, pass them as option to `file_get_content()` and the trick is done.

If the server is using a login system different from cookies let us know, so we can help you

Comment: I dont know wether the system is storing info using cookies or not I am not so experienced but I dont want to use Curl, I remember long ago going through some php code that had variable which store username and password and somehow use those credentials at the top of the code to login. This is the website if you want to see if it stores cookies: http://confluence.rogersdigitalmedia.com

Comment: The link you posted give me a 403-permission denied code
If this IS the page you want to download with file_get_context() you can  just pass username and password as option